# Uncaught Error: No module: ui.directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and trying do like on video but I found problem. I've got this 2 errors:

```
Uncaught Error: No module: ui.directives
Uncaught Error: No module: ui.directives.sortable
```

In my app.js I have like they said on [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable):

```
angular.module('507917App', ['ui.directives.sortable'])
```

And also I've added this line to code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/directives/sortable/src/sortable.js"></script>
```

Looking into path and there is definition for ui.directives:

```
angular.module('ui.directives').directive('uiSortable', [...
```

### Question

Is there anything what I missed or do wrong? Why I've got this errors?

Comment: is sortable.js actually available at that path?

Comment: yes it's available. No errors and I can see on client side this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found **solution**. Before including this script (or other component from angular-ui):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/directives/sortable/src/sortable.js"></script>
```

you need also include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

also first line of app should looks like here:

```
angular.module('507917App', ['ui'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to angular.module('507917App', ['ui.sortable']). It worked for me. If you look in the actual sortable.js file, that's the name of the module. I believe the developer just forgot to update that on the documentations.

Comment: It can be. I've tried with `uiSortable` but forgot about the name convenction. I will trying this when I will be able because for now my server stopped working :P